# Constructive predicative Hausdorffification without Choice

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Can the left adjoint to the inclusion functor $i : \mathbf{Haus} \to \mathbf{Top}$ be constructed (1) constructively, (2) predicatively and (3) in ZF?

If all three conditions (i.e., (1), (2) and (3)) are not possible, why and what is the best we can do?

Comment: Could the downvoter explain?

Comment: I'm not aware of any construction of the Hausdorffification that does use choice...

Comment: @EricWofsey right, I'm including the universal property as part of the construction, and often they use cardinality argument, which involves choice.

Comment: What cardinality argument are you talking about?  I highly doubt it actually uses choice...

Comment: @EricWofsey Let's say we choose the construction that goes like "x~y iff for every function f to a Hausdorff space we have f(x)=f(y)". This has set-theoretic issues, and the solution is to look at Hasdorff space with cardinality smaller than the original space, because **the image would have a smaller cardinality anyway** (this uses choice)

Comment: Huh?  That first construction has no set-theoretic issues whatsoever.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with quantifying over all Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/78200/2060) gives a constructive way.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the first method claims to be surjective, but if you inspect it clearly, it involves having a set of representatives of cardinals less than the original space, something that would involve choice.

Comment: Correction: surjective >> constructive

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about (1) or (2) but Choice definitely isn't needed.  Indeed, I can't think of any construction of the Hausdorffification that uses Choice.

Here's probably the simplest construction.  Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\sim$ be the intersection of all equivalence relations on $X$ for which the quotient space is Hausdorff.  I then claim that $Y=X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff.  Indeed, let $p:X\to Y$ be the quotient map and suppose $p(x),p(y)\in Y$ are distinct points. Then $x\not\sim y$, so there is some equivalence relation ${\sim'}\supseteq{\sim}$ such that $Z=X/{\sim'}$ is Hausdorff and $x\not\sim'y$.  The quotient map $q:X\to Z$ then factors through $p$ via a map $f:Y\to Z$.  Since $Z$ is Hausdorff, $q(x)$ and $q(y)$ have disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ in $Z$.  Then $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ in $Y$.

Thus $Y$ is Hausdorff, and it is now straightforward to show that this operation sending $X$ to $Y$ can be enhanced to a functor that is left adjoint to $i$.

Comment: Where do you get $\sim' \supseteq \sim$ from?

Comment: That is by the definition of $\sim$ as the intersection of equivalence relations for which the quotient is Hausdorff.

Comment: So $(x,y) \notin \sim$ means $(x,y) \notin \displaystyle \bigcap \{ \sim' \mid \text{$X/\sim'$ is $T2$} \}$ means $\neg(\forall \sim', \text{$X/\sim'$ is $T2$} \implies (x,y) \in \sim')$ which means $\exists \sim', \text{$X/\sim'$ is $T2$} \land (x,y) \in \sim'$. I don't see how you get $\sim' \supseteq \sim$.

Comment: $\sim'$ is one of the sets in the collection whose intersection is $\sim$.